# IIS with ARR: Route soap message to different server depending of the soap content

Tags: http, iis, soap, url-rewrite-module, arr

I want to route SOAP messages to different servers depending on the message content.

I tried the Application Request Routing (ARR), but it seems, that you can only route by server variables and the HTTP header.

I found this tutorial: 
[Developing a Custom Rewrite Provider for URL Rewrite Module](http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/developing-a-custom-rewrite-provider-for-url-rewrite-module)

My Question is, can I route depending on the HTTP body with a custom ReplaceProvider (`IRewriteProvider`, `IProviderDescriptor`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible!

Application Request Routing (ARR) can only access information from the http header.